# I'm receiving fatal error when pushing to my branch

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to make the first Git push, but I keep getting this

```
$ git push origin HTML1
fatal: 'HTML1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've checked the configuration and it points to the correct repository. Please help

Comment: The command you've entered is telling git to push a branch named `HTML1` to the remote repository. Try the command over, but with the name of a branch that exists in your local repo -- something like `git push origin master`, since many repositories come with a default branch named `master`.

Comment: I get the same error message
    
    $ git push origin master
    fatal: 'HTML1' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: `git remote show -v`

Comment: You may also try `git branch` to see the name of the branch you are currently on.